# php regex get text between html tags

Tags: php, regex, web-crawler

I want to scrap information about products from other site and the tags in which the price is held looks like that:

```
<span class="text10black">Price: <strong style="color:#000000;">15.90 $</strong></span>
```

In this case I need to extract only **15.90**.
I have tried this:

```
$site_content = file_get_contents('url');
preg_match_all('#<span class="text10black">Price: <strong style="color:#000000;">(.*?) $</strong></span>#', $site_content, $product_prices);
```

Where 'url' is the url from which I scrap the products, but when I check the $product_prices var with var_dump() it says NULL

Comment: You should rarely parse HTML with regex. Use [a PHP DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) instead.

Comment: And apart from what @JayBlanchard said, you'll have to escape the dolar sign with `\$`, because it's a special RegEx character that matches the end of a line

Comment: why not use [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php). This will remove the html part of it and then you can work with it

Comment: @Sphinx but you'd still have to get the correct HTML element, otherwise the rest of the markup (including the "Price:" for example) will also be included.

Comment: @Sphinx If I use strip_tags it will remove all tags from the page and I need only the price which is exactly between these tags that I've showed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Using Simple Dom Parser http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ seems the best idea for doing what you need.

```
$html = file_get_html($url);
foreach($html->find('.text10black strong') as $element)
    var_dump($element->plaintext);
```

Comment: It's not a good practice to use external libraries while you can do it much more performance-wisely internally: [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

Comment: Yeah, @revo, you are right. I suggested the Simple DOM Parser because I find it easier to use.

Comment: Definitely that's the case. Shallowly easier but deeply complex.